# Pytorch freezes when checking dataloader

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

I am running this block of codes for Pytorch and it seems to run forever/freeze in my notebook. I suspect it has something to do with my dataloader but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here. I am running this on a GPU environment and I have previously ran tensorflow v2 keras for the CNN model and it was able to work.

In addition I have also tried to do model.train() and it was also stuck at the first epoch.

Code I am running

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for data, label in train_dataloader:
    print(data.size())
    print(label.size())
    break
print("Time taken: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

The dataloader is implemented with these line of codes

```
train_dataset = ChestXrayDataset("dataset/CheXpert-v1.0-small/train/train", train_data, IMAGE_SIZE, True)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)
```

These are the parameters

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 224                              # Image size (224x224)
IMAGENET_MEAN = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]         # Mean of ImageNet dataset (used for normalization)
IMAGENET_STD = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]          # Std of ImageNet dataset (used for normalization)
BATCH_SIZE = 96                              
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
LEARNING_RATE_SCHEDULE_FACTOR = 0.1           # Parameter used for reducing learning rate
LEARNING_RATE_SCHEDULE_PATIENCE = 5           # Parameter used for reducing learning rate
MAX_EPOCHS = 100                              # Maximum number of training epochs
```

I have checked the dataloader and this is what I got
`<torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader at 0x1f96cd5f6a0>`

The class for ChestXrayDataset is shown here

```
class ChestXrayDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, folder_dir, dataframe, image_size, normalization):
        """
        Init Dataset
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        folder_dir: str
            folder contains all images
        dataframe: pandas.DataFrame
            dataframe contains all information of images
        image_size: int
            image size to rescale
        normalization: bool
            whether applying normalization with mean and std from ImageNet or not
        """
        self.image_paths = [] # List of image paths
        self.image_labels = [] # List of image labels
        
        # Define list of image transformations
        image_transformation = [
            transforms.Resize((image_size, image_size)),
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ]
        
        if normalization:
            # Normalization with mean and std from ImageNet
            image_transformation.append(transforms.Normalize(IMAGENET_MEAN, IMAGENET_STD))
        
        self.image_transformation = transforms.Compose(image_transformation)
        
        # Get all image paths and image labels from dataframe
        for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
            image_path = os.path.join(folder_dir, row.Path)
            self.image_paths.append(image_path)
            if len(row) < 14:
                labels = [0] * 14
            else:
                labels = []
                for col in row[5:]:
                    if col == 1:
                        labels.append(1)
                    else:
                        labels.append(0)
            self.image_labels.append(labels)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Read image at index and convert to torch Tensor
        """
        
        # Read image
        image_path = self.image_paths[index]
        image_data = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB") # Convert image to RGB channels
        
        # TODO: Image augmentation code would be placed here
        
        # Resize and convert image to torch tensor 
        image_data = self.image_transformation(image_data)
        
        return image_data, torch.FloatTensor(self.image_labels[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the length of `dataframe.iterrows()` and `row[5:]` would help.